# Serializer attributes with different name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to create a wrapper arround this url:

`http://localhost:8000/api/foo/?query.in=text&q.value=2`

And need to use a `Serializer` in order to make the framework maps and validates all get params, but I cant have a `query.in` attribute in a Serializer class. Any way to add like an alias to my attribute `query_in` to match with `query.in` when it comes in the `request.GET` data?

Edit: something silimar to db-column in django.models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#db-column